# Barcode printing software with ODBC or database capability?

Tags: windows, barcode

Looking for free (doesn't have to be open source) software that can print barcodes pulling in data from a database (ODBC, JDBC, etc). Keyed input would be preferable where you enter in an item number and the details of that record is pulled from the database and a label is printed with the various bits printed on the label.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest installing [python](http://python.org), then adding [pyBarcode](https://bitbucket.org/whitie/python-barcode/) with `pip install pyBarcode`

- Python comes with a wide range of database interface libraries, either in the standard library or as free plug in components, including [ODBC](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ODBC)
- You can currently pick barcode formats from:

  - code39
  - code128
  - ean
  - ean13
  - ean8
  - gs1
  - gtin
  - isbn
  - isbn10
  - isbn13
  - issn
  - jan
  - pzn
  - upc
  - upca
- Output of the pyBarcode is a .pgn image
- I would suggest generating a page with the bar code and any surrounding text into a file format that your OS/Installed Software [understands how to print](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html), *rather than worrying about specific printers)*, Candidates that can be easily created from python include:

  - HTML (if you have a Web Browser)
  - PDF (if you have Adobe PDF Viewer)
  - DOCX (if you have Word)
  - ODF (if you have LibreOffice)
- It is all free, Open Source & cross platform
- You could extend it to allow multiple IDs to be specified and the results to be laid out in the output document so as to save paper.

Comment: Was looking for a GUI since the product will be used for non-technical people. I appreciate your effort though.

Comment: You have a choice of ways of adding a gui - ipython notebook, wxpython, tk or qt.